# TypeScript Add method to prototype

Tags: typescript, import, prototype

There is a parent Object1.
There is a child Object2.
It turns out something like this class:

```
class Object1 {
   obj: Object2
}
```

I want to add a method to Object2.
The class cannot be inherited because you will have to specify a new class name.
So I'm trying to add a method in the following way:

```
class Object2 {
//Let's say there is such a property
    public name: string = 'asd';
}

interface Object2 {
    log: () => void
}

Object2.prototype.log = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
};
```

This code works!!!

But the point is that the Object2 class is the npm module of the package. I am importing the class. And everything stops working.

```
import { Object2 } from 'somepacket';

interface Object2 {
    log: () => void
}

Object2.prototype.log = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
};
```

And I am getting error:
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration .ts (2440)

**So what's the difference? The Object2 class is exported or is in the same file**

Comment: You need to declare your type as an augmentation of the type exported by the package: `import { Object2 } from 'somepacket';
 declare module 'somepacket' { interface Object2 {
    log: () => void
}}`

Comment: Github Gist? My hacky solution is good but **I'm 100% sure you cannot assign properties to non-declared interface/class/namespace.**

Answer (score 3):

[Add a way to declare prototype modifications](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15818)

`src/MyType.ts`:

```js
export class MyType {
  existingMethod(): void;
}
```

`src/MyTypeExtension.ts`:

```js
import {MyType} from './MyType';

declare module './MyType' {
  interface MyType {
    newMethod(): void;
  }
}

MyType.prototype.newMethod = () => { /* ... */};
```